# Swift + Safe Area + Why Bottom Safe Area Increase

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, autolayout, safearea

I am using IOS SDK 15 and When i autolayout my view to bottom safe area, my view up from 34 to 83 from bottom, when i checked, it is due to safe area increase to 83. Can any one suggest why safe area increase to 83?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of TabBar, which is usually 49. So 34 + 49 = 83.